# My isp has speed limiter, which works for some sites and doesn't for some

Tags: internet

My ISP provides me speed of exact 64kBps for all purposes. But for some sites, the speed just goes 4MBps(note that I know the difference between 'b' and 'B' ). So can I use such speed for all other downloads by using some proxy or tunneling ?

Comment: No way for us to know.  You have to try it.

Answer (score 2):

You could find out the proxies or VPNs that your ISP doesn't throttle, but then they may monitor your speeds and then block those also.